# How to show Dropwizard Metrics Servlet with spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, dropwizard

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-actuator` for getting a `localhost/metrics` endpoint.

Now I also want to use the `dropwizard.metrics` and the `metrics-servlets` dependency. On their webpage (https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/getting-started/) it is stated that with this a `AdminServet` with some kind of admin menu for metrics, healt, threaddump and ping would be created.

But I don't see that servlet. Do I maybe have to register it explicit within spring-boot?

Answer (score 5):

I had to instantiate the servlet explicit and provide a servlet mapping path as follows:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new AdminServlet(),"/metrics/admin/*");
}
```

Comment: I see the menu, but I can't see the matrices as empty from  that link. However directly accessing /metrics gives the result with data. How did you bridge these two?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is working with version 5.0.0, these steps were required to get it work:

```
@Inject
private ServletContext servletContext;

@Inject
private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

@Inject
private HealthCheckRegistry healthCheckRegistry;

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> servletRegistrationBean(){
    servletContext.setAttribute(MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY,
        metricRegistry);
    servletContext.setAttribute(HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY,
        healthCheckRegistry);

    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new AdminServlet(), "/metrics/*");
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382649/1047418